# Problems saving in 2sxc v09.03.00-pre2

Tags: 2sxc

So I should know better than to roll out a pre-release but I did...

Running DNN 9.1.1
2svx 9.0.3.00-pre2

Issues have shown up in 2 areas:
1. The blog app will not save Categories or Tags the blog entry saves OK but strips any Category, Tags, or Author I add. If I edit an existing blog item the categories show up but if I save it they get stripped.

2. A Content Module on the site is stripping a text field upon save. As the field is required it is throwing an error on render.

Since #1 is a more complex piece I'll focus on #2

This is a Content Module with mostly textbox and HTML boxes.
When I edit the item all appears to go well and a Module Updated Event Is Logged 
but one field: Cost never saves to the DB. No error is logged.

The field is a number field.
If I try to edit the cost field properties via admin I get a 400 bad request error. As its a live form I have not tried deleting the field.

Any insight you can provide would be appreciated.

---

Update:

Ok so it looks like this is happening to all content types except strings. If I try to edit content type ie number I get a JS error:

{Message: "Bad Request", ExceptionMessage: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",…}
ExceptionMessage
:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
ExceptionType
:
"System.NullReferenceException"
Message
:
"Bad Request"
StackTrace
:
"   at ToSic.Eav.WebApi.EntitiesController.GetManyForEditing(Int32 appId, List`1 items) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.WebApi\EntitiesController.cs:line 154
↵   at ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.EavApiProxies.EntitiesController.GetManyForEditing(List`1 items, Int32 appId) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Sxc WebApi\EavApiProxies\EntitiesController.cs:line 95
↵   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()"

Here are my headers:

[{"EntityId":1370,"Title":"General Settings"},{"EntityId":1418,"Title":"Number"},{"ContentTypeName":"@number-default","Metadata":{"Key":607,"KeyType":"number","TargetType":2},"Title":"number-default","Prefill":{"Name":"Cost"}}]

Comment: Ok so it looks like this is happening to all content types except strings. If I try to edit content type ie number I get a JS error:

Comment: Our bad :( it should be fixed now in Pre-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fixed in newer releases.